# Multiple identical <select> tags where each option can be selected once

Tags: javascript

I am creating a website where their are 4 identical  dropdown menu's, each dropdown menu has got 10 options. But each of those options can only be selected in one of the dropdown menu's.

So for example:

When I select option 1 in this dropdown menu.

```
<select name="select1">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">2</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

I can't select it in this one. So it should say `disabled` in option one.

```
<select name="select2">
<option value="1" //disabled >1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">2</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

I don't know how to do it myself so I would be very glad if someone could help me.

Comment: you can repopulate the option tags instead

Comment: Either update your select-boxes, using JavaScript, when a choice is made - or simple use a Validation when processing the result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - disable selected options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867362/jquery-disable-selected-options)

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: I am trying to create 4 different <select> dropdown menu's where you can select each option one time. When in the first dropdown option one is selected you cant select it any more in the secen dropdown

Comment: This can be done pretty easily using jQuery; take a look at how to disable elements with jQuery. On the other hand, I believe the meta-solution here is to NOT use four dropdown boxes, and instead use something like a list of checkbox inputs or a multiple-select input, which were designed to accomplish the same goal you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I think you jumped the gun on selecting your chosen answer as the code doesn't quite work.  It doesn't recognize 0 as a valid value and it doesn't re-enable disabled options when going back and changing a previous choice. It will also apply the rule to ALL select inputs on a page instead of only those specified.  My answer does not have any of these issues.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, it is a cleaner way to do it in checkboxes. However, just to improve my JavaScript skills, I came up with something that should answer what you asked for:

```
var boxes, i, disableOthers;

boxes = document.getElementsByTagName('select');

disableOthers = function () {
    'use strict';
    var i, j, k, selectedValues = [],
        options;

    for (i = 0; i < boxes.length; i += 1) {
        selectedValues.push(boxes[i].value);

        for (j = 0; j < boxes.length; j += 1) {
            if (boxes[j] !== boxes[i]) {
                options = boxes[j].querySelectorAll('option');
                for (k = 0; k < options.length; k += 1) {
                    options[k].disabled = (selectedValues.indexOf(options[k].value) > -1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

for (i = 0; i < boxes.length; i += 1) {
    boxes[i].addEventListener('change', disableOthers, false);
}
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MtjUt/)

Comment: Has some bugs especially when going back and changing previously selected options.

Answer (score 0):

To provide a better user experience, you should disable the items using JavaScript when the user selects something in a drop down. Are you using jQuery by any chance?

You should also enforce it on the server because as a general rule, clients are not to be trusted.

Comment: I am not using jQuery or Javascript because I'm not real good with it. Im trying to do it but it isn't working.

Comment: There's not realy anything to show, if tried using php but then I realized that I would have to use Javascript, so I deletet the old script

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, what you are trying to achieve is better done via checkboxes.

Instead of `<select>` do this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="1" value="1">option1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="2" value="2">option2 <br> ...
```

Comment: I am trying to make it so you can select only one of the ten options in the dropdown menu, but once you selected,for instance "1", that you can't select it in the second dropdown menu, which has the same options

Comment: @ChristianPeppelman Ok but in the end what do you want after all the dropdowns have been selected?

Comment: then I upload the results to a database

Comment: @ChristianPeppelman  Ok so when the user selects the 4 check boxes, upload the results and disable the rest of the checkboxes. Its a lot cleaner than having 4 dropdowns, each depending on the previous one. (With your 4th dropdown you would have to "disable" three options)

Comment: I am already using dropdown's , but what I'm trying to do is: their are four dropdown's with identical options, the firt one is de first preference, the second on the second preference and so on. but you can't have the first and second preference be the same, so when you select option "1" in the firt dropdown, you cant select it in the second

Answer (score 0):

The code below does what you are asking.  I also made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sv9cq/1/)

It will correctly disable and enable options as options from ANY of the select inputs are changed.

**The javascript**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

// *** EDIT THIS ***
var selectIds = new Array('select1', 'select2', 'select3', 'select4'); // all of the select input id values to apply the only one option value anywhere rule against

function process_selection(theObj){

    var allSelectedValues = new Array(); // used to store all currently selected values

    // == get all of the currently selected values for all the select inputs
    for (var x=0; x<selectIds.length; x++){
        var v = document.getElementById(selectIds[x]).value; // the value of the selected option for the select input currently being looked at in the loop (selectIds[x])
        // if the selected option value is not an empty string ..
        if(v!==""){
            // store the value of the selected option and it's associated select input id value
            allSelectedValues[v] = selectIds[x];

        }
    }

    // == now work on each option within each select input
    for (var x=0; x<selectIds.length; x++){



        // loop thru all the options of this select input
        var optionObj = document.getElementById(selectIds[x]).getElementsByTagName("option");
        for (var i = 0; i < optionObj.length; i++) {
            var v = optionObj[i].value; // the value of the current option in the iteration
            // only worry about option values that are not an empty string ("")
            if(v!==""){
                if(allSelectedValues[v]){
                    if(allSelectedValues[v] &&  allSelectedValues[v] != selectIds[x]){
                    // disable this option because it is already selected
                    // and this select input is NOT the one that it is selected in
                    optionObj[i].disabled = true;
                    }
                }else{
                    // enable this option because it is not already selected
                    // in any of the other select inputs
                    optionObj[i].disabled = false;
                }
            }
        } // end for (option loop)
    } // end for (select loop)
} // end func
</script>
```

**The HTML that works with the above**

But really the code above will work with any select inputs on your page by editing the one line indicated in the js code above

```
<select name="select1" id="select1" onchange="process_selection(this)">
<option value="">-- choose one --</option>
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>


<select name="select2" id="select2" onchange="process_selection(this)">
<option value="">-- choose one --</option>
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>


<select name="select3" id="select3" onchange="process_selection(this)">
<option value="">-- choose one --</option>
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>


<select name="select4" id="select4" onchange="process_selection(this)">
<option value="">-- choose one --</option>
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```