# jQuery disable select option based on div text

Tags: jquery

I want to disable select options when if div text matces to one of the options class name, here is my code:

```
<select>
    <option class="aaa" value="aaa">aaa</option>
    <option class="bbb" value="bbb">bbb</option>
    <option class="ccc" value="ccc">ccc</option>
    <option class="ddd" value="ddd">ddd</option>
</select>

<div class="field">
    <div>aaa</div>
    <div>ccc</div>
</div>
```

in this example aaa and ccc options shoud be disabled, Thanks!

Comment: You forgot to post the JavaScript you tried.

Comment: possible duplicate - assuming he's using javascript. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867362/jquery-disable-selected-options

Comment: @ntgCleaner sadly those solutions use .attr(), which is no longer the correct approach,  instead of .prop().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('select option').prop('disabled',false); // reset
$('.field > *').each(function() {
    var str = $(this).text();
    $('select option.'+str).prop('disabled',true);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/y7Cv4/

Answer (score 0):

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/73wv9/5/)***

```
$('div').not('.field').each(function () {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    $('option[value=' + txt + ']').prop('disabled',true);
});
```