# Disable all option of listbox except one selected

Tags: jquery, listbox

I have a listbox with a list of countries and 'ALL COUNTRIES' at the top.  I want to disable all of the items except the first if it is selected.  I cannot find a way to do this and leave the first item enabled.  I also want to be able to click on the first again and have it unselect - is there a way to do this?

```
 $("#lbCountries").click(function () {
     $("#lbCountires option").each(function (index) {
        if ($(this).is(':selected') && $(this.val() == 'AL') {
            $(this).prop('disabled', false);
         }
         else {
            $(this).prop('disabled', true);
         }
      });
  });
```

They all get disabled, including the first one.  How can I stop that from happening and be able to click on it again and reverse what has been done?

Comment: fiddle please if possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - disable selected options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867362/jquery-disable-selected-options)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried:

```
$("#lbCountries").click(function () {
     $("#lbCountires option").not(':first-child').each(function (index) {
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
      });
  });
```

Comment: That works like a charm!  I had forgotten about the '.not' capability to filter out things.