# Jquery: How can disabled/enabled option dynamically

Tags: jquery

Can someone help me with the code that I need to activate / deactivate some option?
I have 4 different selects.
First of all I need that jquery check that there are no values ​​greater than the variable stock (I think this is done).
After this I need that when one select changes, check the value of the other selects options and deactivate them if the value is greater than the available stock.
I need to dynamically handle the content of the selects and they are activated / deactivated according to the stock.

I have this code, It works "well" with the first select, but when I change the second select it affects the first one.
I don't know if I explained correctly, but in the jsfiddle/Code I think the idea is better explained
https://jsfiddle.net/apejqfsg/17/

**HTML**

```html
<select id="select1" class="stock">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<select id="select2" class="stock">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<select id="select3" class="stock">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<select id="select4" class="stock">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<p>Max Stock: <span id="disponibles">8</span></p>
```

**JQUERY**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var previous;
  var maxStock = 8;
  $(".stock option")
    .filter(function () {
      return $(this).val() > maxStock;
    })
    .prop("disabled", true);

  $(".stock")
    .focus(function () {
      previous = this.value;
      $(".stock option").each(function () {});
    })
    .change(function () {
      maxStock = maxStock + (previous - this.value);
      var value = this.value;
      var id = $(this).attr("id");
      $(".stock option").each(function () {
        var idParent = $(this).parent().attr("id");
        if (id != idParent) {
          if (this.value > maxStock) {
            this.disabled = true;
          }
        }
      });
      previous = this.value;
      $("#disponibles").html(maxStock);
    });
});
```

Comment: A better explanation of expected behavior would help. Not really clear what specific  problem is

Comment: I gues its a duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867362/jquery-disable-selected-options

Comment: I have a stock of 8 items. I need that all the selects options the values equal or less than stock going active. If in the first select I choose 4 the remaining stock would be 4, I need the other select options greater than the available stock to be deactivated, then in another select I choose 2, the stock would be 2. I need the first one to let me select 4 + 2 and the others only 2.

Comment: Edit the question with that clarification so all readers see it and where it is easier to format for reading

Answer (score 1):

Implementation using on change.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var maxStock = 8;
  var selectedValue;
  var $currentSelect;
  var optionValue;
  var $selectBox;

    // Disable All Options having value > maxStock
  $('.stock option').filter(function() {
    return $(this).val() > maxStock;
  }).prop('disabled', true);


  $('.stock').change(function() {
    $currentSelect = $(this);
    selectedValue = $currentSelect.data('selected-value');
    if (selectedValue) {
      maxStock = maxStock + parseInt(selectedValue);
    }
    selectedValue = parseInt($currentSelect.val());
    maxStock = maxStock - selectedValue;
    $currentSelect.data('selected-value', $currentSelect.val());
    $('#disponibles').text(maxStock);

    // Update options after selection
    $(".stock").each(function() {

      $selectBox = $(this);
      if (!$selectBox.is($currentSelect)) {
         selectedValue = parseInt($selectBox.val());
        if (!selectedValue) {
          selectedValue = 0;
        }
        $selectBox.find('option').each(function() {
          optionValue = $(this).val();
          if (optionValue > maxStock && optionValue > selectedValue) {
            $(this).prop('disabled', true);
          } else {
            $(this).prop('disabled', false);
          }
        });
      }
    });

  });
});
```

You can test using fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/NoumanAhmad/0pdzkb8s/43/)

Answer (score 0):

probably best to perform disabling of options during `focus` rather than on `change`.

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    ...
    $(".stock").focus(function () {
        var otherMaxStock=maxStock;
        var currId=$(this).attr('id');
        $( ".stock" ).each(function( index ) {
            if (currId!=$(this).attr('id'))
                otherMaxStock-=$(this).val();
        });
        $(this).find("option:gt("+otherMaxStock+")").prop( "disabled", true );
    }).change(function() {
        /*
        maxStock=maxStock+(previous-this.value);
        ...
        $("#disponibles").html(maxStock); */
```

Comment: exactly, thank you very much! I was dizzy thinking about this.